# How to see my inbox?

Tags: support

A moderator is trying to talk to me, but I can only see truncated text in the Stack Exchange notification system (top left)

How do I open my "inbox"?

The original post was removed, but he's still sending updates to me somehow, but it's like a one-way, interrupted "conversation":

> chat message on Tavern on the Meta
>   @maxhodges I contacted the user you had a bad run-in with, but I had to remove your meta post. Pe...

Answer (score 4):

That message was posted in the [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chatroom. You can drop by the room to see the full message and reply to it.

In such notifications, the name of the room acts as a link to the room. So you will be able to click on `Tavern on the Meta` to enter the room directly from your notification.

Comment: thanks. seems like a bug. When I click the notification I get a "this topic has been removed". it should instead link to that chatroom. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you look at your inbox by clicking on the StackExchange button visible on the top left side, each message has a link: If the message was for a comment, the link takes to the comment; if the message was for a chat message the link takes to the page where you can read the full message, and reply to it from the menu accessible from the arrow on the left side of the post. (The arrow should be visible when you hover the message.)

[image: screenshot]

In the first case, if the question has been deleted, you cannot access anymore the comment. In the latter case, if the post has been deleted, you probably are not anymore able to see it.